# Join two fields with Linq query

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to show Name and Surname in a textbox with an autocomplete function, the problem is that I have these two fields in different columns in my Database (attached image)

[image: Screenshot]

I want to know if there is a way to concatenate these two variables so that the user can see in the Texbox the full name (v_Nombre + v_Apellido), since at present I only show the name

Any help for me?

View:

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#usuario").autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("BuscarUsuario")'
            });
        });
 </script>

      <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Usuario que retiro</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkusuario" id="idcheckusuario" checked="checked" value="true" />
                    @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "usuario" })
                </div>
```

My Controller:

```
 public JsonResult BuscarUsuario(string term)
        {
            using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
            {
                List<string> resultado;

                resultado = db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.v_Nombre.Contains(term)).Select(n => n.v_Nombre).Take(10).ToList();

                return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to concatenate in your Select:

```
.Select(n => n.v_Nombre + " " + n.v_Apellido)
```